# Javascript Object and Properties: Adding & Accessing Properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I want some clarification when it comes to accessing objects as well as the adding of properties, I'm totally new to Javascript.

I have an object like so:

```
var device = { 
               dev1 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "AIR" },
               dev2 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "BEE" }
             }
```

<s>Is there a reason why it botches up when I do these two lines? (I'm not using a browser but running purely on Javascript as an application.)</s>

```
console.log( device.dev1['version'] ) returns undefined
console.log( device['dev1'].version ) returns undefined
```

Now for adding properties... I want to use String type property key names. Meaning I don't want it to look like this. It has to follow the object I described above by using the "  "s.

```
     dev1 : { version : "1.0", name: "AIR" }
```

Is there a way to define property name as strings? Can it be done like this?

```
var newKey = "health";
device['dev1'].newKey = newValue;
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: In your last example, you want `device['dev1'][newKey]`, which evaluates to `device['dev1']['health']`.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `dev1 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "AIR" }`.  If you add the comma both `console.log` statements work as you'd expect.

Comment: As steaks said about the `,`. Also, `console.log` always `return`s _undefined_, but it logs stuff to the console, too.

Comment: I don't know if anyone has told you yet, but you're missing a comma after the first object declaration on line two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I fix your syntax error, your code works fine:

```
var device = { 
  dev1 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "AIR" }, // added comma here
  dev2 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "BEE" }
};
console.log( device.dev1['version'] ); // 1.0
console.log( device['dev1'].version ); // 1.0
console.log( device.dev1.version );    // 1.0
```

And property names are *always* strings. They cannot be anything else.  If it looks like the property name is not a string, it's simply shorthand for a string.

You can use the bracket syntax when the property name is a string in a variable, for both getting and setting:

```
var newKey = 'someName';
var newValue = 'woot';

device.dev1[newKey] = newValue;
console.log(device.dev1[newKey]);  // woot
console.log(device.dev1.someName); // woot
```

---

So if you know the property name ahead of time, then the shorthand dot property syntax `obj.propName` is identical to `obj['propName']`. But if you don't know the property name ahead of time, then you must use the bracket syntax. `obj[propNameString]`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after your dev1 object:

```
var device = { 
    dev1 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "AIR" },
    dev2 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "BEE" }
}
```

For your question about adding keys, you would want to use dot-notation when possible, and array-notation for variable key names:

```
var newKey = "health";
device.dev1[newKey] = newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the comma (`,`)

```
var device = { 
    dev1 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "AIR" }, // <----
    dev2 : { "version" : "1.0", "name" : "BEE" }
};

var newKey = "health", newValue = 'newValue';
device.dev1.newKey = newValue; 
device['dev1']['newKey'] = newValue;
```

[**Working Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eapC/3/)